# Some people here are abusing their power

Tags: discussion

So I answered this question:

[Pros Playing in 4:3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/167030/pros-playing-in-43/167077)

I wrote as a comment below "MAD PAINT SKILLZ!". This was meant as a joke. But someone deleted it. Enough is enough..

Yes, yes, I know you have your shitty "no freedom of speech here" answer, but you know what? I don't care. If we cannot have some fun here on this site, then why should I waste more time here helping people with answers?

This is going too far and I am appalled by how much censoring here is done. I know those people won't face any consequences for their actions, but stop it. Otherwise rename stackexchange.com to nofunallowed.com.

Comment: I'm not sure why your comment would have been deleted (and, surely, if all of the "freehand circle" injoke comments around the site get left alone, I don't know why yours would have been objectionable), but writing this as an angry rant isn't really going to help anything.

Comment: Chat is where we go for fun.  Yes, you're allowed to put jokes in the comments, but they should be interesting, funny, and relevant, none of which seem to apply to your comment.

Comment: @PanicBomb It is not the first time this happens. I have simply enough of it. I have seen those types of comments on other posts multiple times with plenty of upvotes. So I dont know why mine is any different and because of that, it is abuse.

Comment: @MBraedley Then I am going to report every funny comment I find to the moderators. Let's see if they get deleted as well :).

Comment: @Assylum please don't

Comment: I have deleted my answer on this question, please also delete my account. I am done. Stack Exchange my butt.

Comment: Take a breath, step away from the site for a day or two, and if after that you still feel you want your account deleted, @badp's answer has the proper method of doing so. Or you could skip the first step and proceed with the deletion now - but it's more hassle for everyone involved if you want it undeleted after the emotions have cooled.

Comment: @TrentHawkins Actually, SE has specifically stopped recovering accounts after they've been deleted.  You delete it, it's gone.  Permanently.

Comment: @Frank oh, right. Well, take a breather and cool off first, or delete now and regret it later.

Comment: It should be noted also that comments can easily be deleted by a relatively small number of flags from ordinary users with *no moderator intervention*.

Comment: @MBraedley http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/149903/xbox-360-freezing-and-not-turning-on#comment202247_149903 I found that not funny. Taking you by your own standard, delete it please.

Comment: @Assylum On the most important aspect - relevancy - that comment scores highly.  Also, I think it's funny, and apparently so do 11 other people.  Or they at least get the reference, which you apparently don't.

Comment: @MBradley I do get the reference. but your comment had a chance to be seen. Mine did not, it was deleted after 5 minutes. But I knew you gonna argue, since ya'll are just a bunch of hypocrites.

Comment: Look, I've had comments deleted. I've had them deleted as not constructive.  When it's happened, I frowned and thought to myself "awe, I thought that was funny" and then got on with my day.  You know why?  Because _comments don't matter!_

Comment: I've had a comment that had a great many upvotes deleted, too.  "Every time someone asks for a reason for downvotes, an angel kills a kitten."  It was funny, and succinct.  It still got deleted.  I shrugged and kept going.

Comment: @Assylum You need to chill. You got upset by a lighthearted comment made by me a while ago. I even ended the comment with a smiley. It really takes someone with no appreciation of humour to get upset with it. It's ironic that you are the one here complaining about people lacking humour. Maybe it's time to take a look at your own behaviour.

Comment: [Instructions for Deleting Account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account) -- toodles.

Answer (score 16):

I've said it before, and I'll say it again.

> The problem is that this is the internet. There are a rather large number of people who frequent Arqade, and our tastes can differ wildly. That's part of being a community. In such a place, there are things you are and are not allowed to say. Just because you don't find it offensive does not mean it's not. The community may view it as offensive. In order to participate in the community, you have to conform to the norms inherent to it.
>
> Obviously, your norms differ from the community's. That does not give you the right to impose your standards on the community as a whole.

I was talking about offensive comments, but my entire [answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7464/the-state-of-this-website/7466#7466) applies.  You are part of a community.  You must adapt to the community, not the other way around.

Comment: I would agree with this. The best way to change a community is to gain respect in it first by conforming to the culture, and then change it through positive actions.

Answer (score 15):

The comment was flagged as not constructive. A moderator reviewed the flag and agreed with it. I suppose he didn't like your joke?

While I can agree that the deletion was unnecessary, suggesting that a moderator should receive "consequences" for moderating will leave you sorely disappointed.

If you would like to delete your account, I wish you good luck in your future endeavours. The instructions are here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: "Didn't like it" is not a valid reason. There are lots of comments and jokes on this site I don't like, but I don't report them to have them deleted simply for the sake of it. There was no rule broken. cc @AnnaLear

Comment: @assylum your choice not to report every single comment that annoys you is appreciated — comments are a second class citizen and the less time is spent worrying about them the more time we can spend in the actual raison d'être of this website; if this results in inconsistent moderation, so be it. We can't read every single comment (or post) made on the site.

Comment: @assylum Didn't like it IS a valid reason. Though there are criteria for deletion, there will always be cases that lie in the grey area. It's up to the moderator's discretion to delete or keep it and that's up to the moderator's opinion.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a *"shitty no-freedom-of-speech-here"* answer.

[image]