# Giving in to offended people is never a good idea

Tags: support

Since no moderator bothered to answer me privately, I drag this into public. For years I had the same user name here and now I am forced to change it because 1 Person got offended? That is a stupid thing to do. Do I really need to start reporting every user who's name I don't like to put your system ad absurdum?

This is something that is bad on Stack Exchange since I know it. It even says in the mail:

> We get it; not everyone shares the same sense of humor

So why do I need to change my name just because 1 other person does not share my humor? That is fricking stupid and I request my user name back. Also, what is offensive about having `Allahu al akbar` in my Bio? Which part of it is not professional? I am pretty sure if I put "In God We Trust" in there, it won't get removed, because, muh, 'murica.

---

[image: screenshot]

Moderators announcing actions against me in front of other users. Nice. How is *that* not offensive and allowed? But I guess this kind of bullying is allowed here as long as it is coming from the mods and users in the clique of "The Bridge". I have been criticizing this for a while, but yeah. No change gonna happen here.

---

And of course, when I reply in a normal manner to people here, they immediately feel the need to run off to chat and trash talk about how stupid I supposedly am and getting peoples attention so they report my comments so they are automatically removed.

[image]

I cannot fathom, why nobody here sees this toxic behavior as a problem. I do. This is borderline harassment and should be stopped.

Comment: We're locking this post since there's nothing more to be said on this topic, and the comments have ceased to be constructive.

Answer (score 10):

> Since no moderator bothered to answer me privately, I drag this into public.

Moderators are people too, with lives, jobs and families to attend to. We can't respond to everything right away and certainly not when it's an accusation of foul play that requires extra investigation and attention.

> For years I had the same user name here...

So you managed to fly under the radar for a little while but quite frankly: that's no excuse. It doesn't excuse the actual content of your display name or bio. We removed the contents of both in accordance with Stack Exchange's '[Be Nice](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)' policy, (which was linked in the initial Private Message):

> ...these three guidelines may help:
>
> 1. **Rudeness and belittling language are not okay.** Your tone should match the way you'd talk in person with someone you respect and whom you want to respect you. If you don't have time to say something politely, just leave it for someone who does.
> 2. **Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions.** Don't expect new users to know all the rules — they don't. And be patient while they learn. If you're here for help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you. Everyone here is volunteering, and no one responds well to demands for help.
> 3. **Don't be a jerk.** These are just a few examples. If you see them, flag them:
>
>    - **Name-calling**. Focus on the post, not the person. That includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to posts (like "lazy", "ignorant", or "whiny").
>    - **Bigotry of any kind.** Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc. will not be tolerated. At all. (Those are just a few examples; when in doubt, just don't.)
>    - **Inappropriate language or attention.** Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive. Also, this is not a dating site.
>    - **Harassment and bullying.** If you see a hostile interaction, flag it. If it keeps up, disengage — we'll handle it. If something needs staff attention, you can use the contact us link at the bottom of every page.

Your Bio fell afoul of Point 3.2: *"Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on... religion"*, while your Username falls under Point 3.3: *"Inappropriate language... avoid vulgar terms"*. Likewise, your response and general attitude towards this situation, calling people 'Snowflakes' etc basically runs counter to the entire point of the policy.

> ...and now I am forced to change it because 1 Person got offended?

This seems to be a sticking point with you, so let me be **perfectly** clear: while it may have been a flag that alerted us to the content of your name & bio, the removal of such is a moderator-level call to make and it was made in accordance with the policy listed above. **Disabuse yourself of the notion that the removal actions were the blind result of someone being 'offended'.**

> Also, what is offensive about having Allahu al akbar in my Bio? I am pretty sure if I put "In God We Trust" in there, it won't get removed...

You have **never** had 'Allahu al akbar' in your Profile Bio nor your Username. There is an audit trail attached to every edit made to your profile (by you **or** a moderator for that matter) that we can check for situations like this, and the only content ever to exist in your bio was *'Allahu Snackbar'*, which is mocking the religion, not supporting it. Don't attempt to twist this into a religion vs religion thing, especially when backing it up with a blatant lie.

### Next Steps for your consideration

The removal of your display name and bio and subsequent heads up via PM were done in good faith, with the hope of a happier (or at the very least *calmer*) resolution than this has become.

What happens next is entirely up to you. As a warning: any continued rudeness, aggression and contempt towards your fellow community members will be met with harsher penalties.

Given the attitude in this meta, comments, chat, the PMs, and especially the poor response towards other community members and the community itself, I would *strongly* urge you to review the [Be Nice](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy in its entirety. If in future you disagree with an action taken, so long as you come to the table in a calm and civil fashion we'd be happy to discuss it with you.

Comment: badp replied to me in this thread as well: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8617/some-people-here-are-abusing-their-power Nobody changed my name. So stop it with the "flying under the radar". Because it is simply an excuse. And btw, calling out these things is neither rude nor offensive...

Comment: @BadSnowflake Calling out these things is not rude nor offensive, correct.  The *method* you use to call them out, however, most assuredly is.  It's your hostile tone and lack of effort for other perspectives that people see and respond to.  Seriously, review the Be Nice policy; it can only help you.

Comment: @BadSnowflake Badp has already responded to you 2 days ago in PM regarding both the comment he made and the second username reset. Regarding the community's involvement: *you brought this situation to them* - by posting on meta you involved the community at large, Frank and everyone else have every right to comment or vote here. It is **your** angry, sarcastic response, name calling, and air of contempt for other users that is the issue: Any solid argument you may have is dismissed by most, because you've managed to insult the entire community while you're at it.

Answer (score 8):

Again, [I refer to my previous answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8620/20456).

> The main problem I see is that you seem to think that as long as you, personally, do not find something offensive, it's OK and should be allowed to stay.
>
> The problem is that this is the internet. There are a rather large number of people who frequent Arqade, and our tastes can differ wildly. That's part of being a community. In such a place, there are things you are and are not allowed to say. Just because you don't find it offensive does not mean it's not. The community may view it as offensive. In order to participate in the community, you have to conform to the norms inherent to it.
>
> Obviously, your norms differ from the community's. That does not give you the right to impose your standards on the community as a whole.
>
> You have your right of free speech. You CAN say whatever you like. But don't expect it to stick around if it doesn't meet the community's standards. There wasn't even a penalty for saying such. For you to criticize a community's actions regarding a comment implies that your rights are more important than anyone else's. They're not. In this instance, a quorum of members found your comment offensive, and it got deleted. I believe it takes six members for the system to auto-delete comments flagged offensive/spam. Why should your single opinion outweigh six other member's opinion?
>
> In short, every community has social norms and conventions. In order to participate, it's not up to the community to adapt to you, but for you to adapt to the community.